# Visibility/binding problem with a usercontrol base class

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, visibility, base-class

I have an app and a class library.
I'm using ninject to bind all viewmodels and Syncfusion as a third party extension.

The main app displays a RibbonGallery that contain Sine and Triangle waves.
When selecting a wave the wave properties become visible for the user to change.

Several properties are the same for both waves (Frequency, Amplitude and Offset) so I use a usercontrol base class in order to implement the components just once.

The class library contains an implementation of a usercontrol base class name 
StandardView.

Each wave shows the StandardView and property of his own (Phase).

When selecting a wave in the main app, the visibility is set according to selection.

When writing input in the TextBox the ComboBox pops up automatically and the user can select from it.

My problem is that if the user writes input to the Sine wave, then he changes the selection to Triangle wave then he back again to Sine wave - he will not be able to select any item from the ComboBox - as if the items are frozen.

I suspect that the ComboBox popup correctly, then the previous ComboBox popup in front, and that causes the user to not be able to select any item.

[Video example of the problem](https://gph.is/2PWA0nd)

[Source code](https://ufile.io/oxtq6)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: (added source code to the question)

**Class library:**
StandardView(only for Frequency)

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!--Standard Frequency-->
            <Label Content="Frequency" Width="120" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Label>

            <syncfusion:DoubleTextBox Name="StandardFrequency" Width="140" Margin="2" Padding="1"
                                  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Focusable="True"  
                                  EnterToMoveNext="True" AcceptsReturn="False"
                                  IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=readonly, Path=IsChecked}"                                                          
                                  Value="{Binding FrequencyValue, Source={x:Static local:ViewModelLocator.StandardViewModel}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                  NumberDecimalDigits="8" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" 
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"   
                                  ContextMenu="{x:Null}" >
                <syncfusion:DoubleTextBox.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=ApplyValue}" Key="Enter" />
                </syncfusion:DoubleTextBox.InputBindings>
            </syncfusion:DoubleTextBox>

            <ComboBox Name="StandardFrequencyVariable" Width="70" Margin="2" Padding="1" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding FrequencyValues, Source={x:Static local:ViewModelLocator.StandardViewModel}}" DisplayMemberPath="Key"  SelectedValuePath="Key" 
                              SelectedValue="{Binding FrequencyNodeCategory, Source={x:Static local:ViewModelLocator.StandardViewModel}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              IsDropDownOpen="{Binding IsFrequencyDropDownOpen, Source={x:Static local:ViewModelLocator.StandardViewModel}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                              
                               IsHitTestVisible="False" >
                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" >
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

StandardViewModel:

```
 public class StandardViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public StandardViewModel()
    { 


    }



    #region Public Properties

    private double frequencyValue;
    public double FrequencyValue
    {
        get
        {
            return frequencyValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if( value != frequencyValue )
            {
                frequencyValue = value;
                OnPropertyRaised( "FrequencyValue" );

                IsFrequencyDropDownOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }



    private string frequencyNodeCategory;
    public string FrequencyNodeCategory
    {
        get
        {
            return frequencyNodeCategory;
        }
        set
        {
            if( value != frequencyNodeCategory )
            {
                frequencyNodeCategory = value;
                OnPropertyRaised( "FrequencyNodeCategory" );

                IsFrequencyDropDownOpen = false;
            }
        }

    }



    private bool isFrequencyDropDownOpen;
    public bool IsFrequencyDropDownOpen
    {
        get
        {
            return isFrequencyDropDownOpen;
        }
        set
        {
            if( value != isFrequencyDropDownOpen )
            {
                isFrequencyDropDownOpen = value;
                OnPropertyRaised( "IsFrequencyDropDownOpen" );

                if( isFrequencyDropDownOpen )
                    return;
            }
        }
    }






    public Dictionary<string, int> FrequencyValues
    {
        get
        {
            return frequencyValues;
        }
        set
        {
            frequencyValues = value;
        }
    }



    public Dictionary<string, int> frequencyValues = new Dictionary<string, int>(){
    {"µHz", -6},
    {"mHz", -3},
    {"Hz", 0},
    {"KHz", 3},
    {"MHz", 6},
    {"GHz", 9}
    };



    #endregion








    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyRaised( string propertyName = null )
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if( handler != null )
            handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
}
```

SineView: (TriangleView is basically the same)

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <local:StandardView />

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <!--Phase-->

            <Label Content="Phase" Width="120" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></Label>

            <syncfusion:DoubleTextBox Name="StandardSinePhase" Width="140" Margin="2" Padding="1" 
                                TextWrapping="NoWrap" Focusable="True"                                                             
                                EnterToMoveNext="True" AcceptsReturn="False"
                                IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=readonly, Path=IsChecked}" 
                                Value="{Binding StandardSinePhaseValue, Source={x:Static local:ViewModelLocator.SineViewModel}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                NumberDecimalDigits="1" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  
                                ContextMenu="{x:Null}" >
                <syncfusion:DoubleTextBox.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=ApplyValue}" Key="Enter" />
                </syncfusion:DoubleTextBox.InputBindings>
            </syncfusion:DoubleTextBox>

            <Label Name="PhaseDegLabel" Content="Deg." Margin="2" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

SineViewModel:

```
  public class SineViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SineViewModel()
    {

    }



    private double standardSinePhaseValue;
    public double StandardSinePhaseValue
    {
        get
        {
            return standardSinePhaseValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if( value != standardSinePhaseValue )
            {
                standardSinePhaseValue = value;
                OnPropertyRaised( "StandardSinePhaseValue" );
            }
        }
    }



    private bool isSineChecked = true;
    public bool IsSineChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return isSineChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            if( value != isSineChecked )
            {
                isSineChecked = value;
                OnPropertyRaised( "IsSineChecked" );

                if( isSineChecked == true )
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyRaised( string propertyName = null )
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if( handler != null )
            handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
}
```

BooleanToVisibilityConverter:

```
   public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{  
    private bool triggerValue = false;
    public bool TriggerValue
    {
        get
        {
            return triggerValue;
        }
        set
        {
            triggerValue = value;
        }
    } 
    private bool isHidden;
    public bool IsHidden
    {
        get
        {
            return isHidden;
        }
        set
        {
            isHidden = value;
        }
    }

    private object GetVisibility( object value )
    {
        if( !( value is bool ) )
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        bool objValue = ( bool )value;
        if( ( objValue && TriggerValue && IsHidden ) || ( !objValue && !TriggerValue && IsHidden ) )
        {
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        if( ( objValue && TriggerValue && !IsHidden ) || ( !objValue && !TriggerValue && !IsHidden ) )
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return GetVisibility( value );
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        if( ( Visibility )value == Visibility.Visible )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

IoC:

```
   public static class IoC
{
    #region Public Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// The kernel for the IoC container
    /// </summary> 
    public static IKernel Kernel { get; private set; } = new StandardKernel();

    #endregion


    #region Construction

    /// <summary>
    /// Setups the IoC container, binds all information required
    /// </summary>
    public static void Setup()
    {
        // Bind all required view models

        BindViewModels();
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Binds all singleton view models.
    /// </summary> 
    private static void BindViewModels()
    {
        // Bind to a single instance of application view model 

        Kernel.Bind<CanvasViewModel>().ToConstant( new CanvasViewModel() );
        Kernel.Bind<SineViewModel>().ToConstant( new SineViewModel() );
        Kernel.Bind<TriangleViewModel>().ToConstant( new TriangleViewModel() );

        Kernel.Bind<StandardViewModel>().ToConstant( new StandardViewModel() );


    }





    #endregion


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a service from the IoC, of the specified type
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> the type to get</typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns> 
    internal static T Get<T>()
    {
        return Kernel.Get<T>();
    }

}
```

ViewModelLocator:

```
    public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public static ViewModelLocator Instance { get; private set; } = new ViewModelLocator();

    public static CanvasViewModel CanvasViewModel => IoC.Get<CanvasViewModel>();
    public static SineViewModel SineViewModel => IoC.Get<SineViewModel>();
    public static TriangleViewModel TriangleViewModel => IoC.Get<TriangleViewModel>();

    public static StandardViewModel StandardViewModel => IoC.Get<StandardViewModel>();



}
```

**Application**

App.xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup( StartupEventArgs e )
    {
        // Setup IoC 
        IoC.Setup();

        // Show the main window
        Current.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

}
```

MainWindow:

```
    <Grid>
    <local:CanvasView />
</Grid>
```

CanvasView:

```
    <Grid> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <!--Hides control if boolean value is true-->
        <core:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="HiddenIfTrue" TriggerValue="True" IsHidden="True"/>
        <!--Hides control if boolean value is false-->
        <core:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="HiddenIfFalse" TriggerValue="False" IsHidden="True"/>
        <!--Collapses control if boolean value is true  InvBoolToVis-->
        <core:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="CollapsedIfTrue" TriggerValue="True" IsHidden="False"/>
        <!--Collapses control if boolean value is false  BoolToVis-->
        <core:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="CollapsedIfFalse" TriggerValue="False" IsHidden="False"/>

    </Grid.Resources>

    <syncfusion:RibbonBar Grid.Row="0" Header="Waves" IsLauncherButtonVisible="False" >
        <syncfusion:RibbonGallery Name="Standard" ItemWidth="90" ExpandWidth="0" MenuIconBarEnabled="True" VisualMode="InRibbon"   >
            <syncfusion:RibbonGalleryItem Name="Sine"   Content="Sine"
            Command="{Binding Path=SineCommand, Source={x:Static core:ViewModelLocator.CanvasViewModel}}" 
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSineChecked, Source={x:Static core:ViewModelLocator.SineViewModel}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"  />



            <syncfusion:RibbonGalleryItem Name="Triangle"   Content="Triangle" 
                                      Command="{Binding Path=TriangleCommand, Source={x:Static core:ViewModelLocator.CanvasViewModel}}" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsTriangleChecked, Source={x:Static core:ViewModelLocator.TriangleViewModel}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />



        </syncfusion:RibbonGallery>
    </syncfusion:RibbonBar>



        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
            <syncfusion:GroupBar Name="ParametersPanel" AllowDragandDrop="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" MinWidth="350" ItemHeaderHeight="30" VisualMode="MultipleExpansion" AnimationSpeed="0" >

                <!--Group Bar Item-->
                <syncfusion:GroupBarItem x:Name="StandardParameters" HeaderText="{Binding StandardParametersCaption, Source={x:Static core:ViewModelLocator.CanvasViewModel}}" 
                                         ShowInGroupBar="True" IsExpanded="True"  >

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition /> 
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <core:SineView Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSineChecked, 
                                   Source={x:Static core:ViewModelLocator.SineViewModel},
                                   Converter={StaticResource CollapsedIfFalse},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />

                    <core:TriangleView Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsTriangleChecked, 
                                       Source={x:Static core:ViewModelLocator.TriangleViewModel},
                                       Converter={StaticResource CollapsedIfFalse},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Grid>

                </syncfusion:GroupBarItem>




            </syncfusion:GroupBar>
        </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: (Nearly) no one will every download an external linked code and debug it for you. Better provide an inline [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, it is a minimal example that I started from scratch. 
I'll upload my code to my question as well.

Comment: I found couple of issues after debugging your code
1. Your ST view is singleton. You r creating constant object in DI. and binding x:static in your view, which cause the problem. i.e. when you try to change the value of sine view, it also effects triangleView. 
2. As your standard VM is singleton, so when a NotifyProperty raised for one item lets say IsFrequencyDropDownOpen, it also impacts on hidden view. In your case when NP raised for sine view, but triangleview is also notified, also triangle view is last element in your grid. therefore you are unable to select from sineview dropdown.

Comment: Thank you @KamranAsim for taking the time to answer my question.
Can you please elaborate on how to fix those issues?
I'm trying to solve that without any success so far.
Also, is there a solution for the last element on grid issue? So that the user could select from the SineView dropdown.
Thanks again.

Comment: I have shared solution. please verify. I hope it ll fulfill your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have uploaded sample on github. Please verify.
[WPF Sample](https://github.com/mKamiAsim/wpfSample.git)
 1. Derive your triangle VM and sine VM from standard VM. As they both are supposed to use some common features. 
 2. Set dataContext TriangleView to TriangleVM and same for sine VM
 3. Adjust binding.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. It fixes the problem with selecting from the SineView dropdown, however, I need both FrequencyValue and FrequencyNodeCategory to be shared across my application, i.e if the user changes FrequencyValue in Sine and then switches to Triangle he will see the same FrequencyValue.